# In Django-CMS, how to redirect a page on a condition?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using Django 1.3 with Django-CMS

I have a multilanguage page, with urls
*/en/hello/world*
*/it/ciao/mondo*

Both urls point to same page, different translations.

At present, if an user write
*/it/hello/world*
the italian page is presented

I do not want two urls for the same exact content, I'd like to redirect to
*/it/ciao/mondo*

I tried to use in a middleware
**get_page_from_request** (after importing it from cms.utils.page_resolver )
to check that the page absolute url is equal to the requested url
but it always return None

How can I achieve what I want (or have **get_page_from_request** return 
something ? )

Comment: how about discussing this on django-cms-developers mailing list instead of stackoverflow and get this into core?

Comment: I created time ago a ticket at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/910 but it is still labeled "design decision needed". Need more people interested on it I suppose

Comment: if it's DDN, discuss it on the django-cms-developers mailing list or convince me on IRC